# making predictions from 2D data

Tags: python, keras, regression, prediction

I am working on making prediction from 2d data. Data size is 7640x200x2; for each 200x2 matrix, I want a 2x1 array predicted from it. I am a beginner, and I am confused how to bulid a useful model. I have tried a cnn+lstm model, but the result was really bad. Could anyone please give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem there are any sequences as said in the question, so LSTM isn't applicable here.

(200x2) --> (2,1) can be simply done by a dense network after flattening:

```
inp (200x2) --> flatten (to 400) --> dense(2, activation=identity)
```

2D convolutional layers may be put in between `inp` layer and `flatten` layer:

```
inp --> conv2d --> flatten
```

Depends on the range of the expected output, the activation in output dense layer can be changed, for example, use 'relu' instead of 'identity' if output is always positive.

Comment: Thanks! I am now facing another problem, the training loss isn't decreasing and I think I used a wrong way to normalize the data. Each (200,2) matrix has 2 features, how should I normalize it correctly?

Comment: the popular way to normalise is finding abs max, and divide all values by that abs max